# About Java nested Enum type

Tags: java

I will give the example java code for this circumstances：

```java
    // StateEntity interface define:
    
    public interface StateEntity extends IDEntity { // the IDEntity define getId & setId
        static int processBitState(int state, boolean op, int pos) {
            if (op) {
                state = Bits.set(state, pos);
            } else {
                state = Bits.clear(state, pos);
            }
            return state;
        }
    
        static <E extends Enum<E>, T extends StateEntity> int gatherState(Class<E> enumType, int state, @NotNull T data) {
            try {
                Method getJsonFieldName = enumType.getMethod("getJsonFieldName");
                Method getPosition = enumType.getMethod("getPosition");
                BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(data.getClass());
                PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
                for (E bitSet : EnumSet.allOf(enumType)) {
                    String fieldName = (String) getJsonFieldName.invoke(bitSet);
                    for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
                        if (propertyDescriptor.getName().equals(fieldName)) {
                            Method reader = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
                            Boolean value = (Boolean) reader.invoke(data);
                            state = processBitState(state, value, (Integer) getPosition.invoke(bitSet));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IntrospectionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return state;
        }
    
        <E extends Enum<E>> Class<E> getStateType();
    
        Integer getState();
    
        void setState(Integer state);
    }
    
    // Impl class:
    
    public class StateEntityClass implements StateEntity {
        Long id;
        Integer state;
    
        @Override
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        @Override
        public <E extends Enum<E>> Class<E> getStateType() {
            return (Class<E>) (BitSet.class);
        }
    
        @Override
        public Integer getState() {
            return state;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void setState(Integer state) {
            this.state = state;
        }
    
        public enum BitSet {
            ACTIVATION(0),
            FREEZE(1),
            UPDATE(2);
    
            private final int position;
    
            BitSet(int v) {
                position = v;
            }
    
            @NotNull
            public String getName() {
                return name().toLowerCase().replaceAll("_", "-");
            }
    
            @NotNull
            public String getJsonFieldName() {
                return NameConverter.snakeCaseToCamelCase("is_" + name().toLowerCase());
            }
    
            public int getPosition() {
                return position;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // used:
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            StateEntityClass e = new StateEntityClass();
    
            // first method, this statement error:
            e.setState(StateEntity.gatherState(e.getStateType(), e.getState() == null ? 0 : e.getState(), e));
            // second method, but this statement ok:
            e.setState(StateEntity.gatherState(StateEntityClass.BitSet.class, e.getState() == null ? 0 : e.getState(), e));
            // why?? how change the first method
        }
    }
```

I have some class implements `StateEntity`, so I must use the first method for generic.

- How do I change my code to use the first method?
- What is the Java way to process these circumstances problems?

The Enum content is unrelated, the `StateEntity` implements class has self Enum for the state.

Comment: Try giving StateEntity a type parameter: interface StateEntity<E extends Enum<E>>

Comment: @tgdavies yes, It works!! thx. but why?

Comment: Why don't you use an Interface for your `getJsonFieldName` and `getPosition` methods? Using reflection smells bad here.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. yes! use interface is great. but, enum how to implements interface?

Comment: If not use Reflection, how to iterate the Enum Constants? @GuillaumeF.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/java-extensible-enum-with-interface

Comment: You can iterate Enum Constants with `MyEnum.values()`. Please read the Java documentation.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. MyEnum.values() need enum Type name, if the enum is variable, cannot use the syntax.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I change the enum to implements interface. thank you.

Comment: @upduan, now that the question has been edited, I no longer understand what was being asked. You can post an answer to your own question and (after waiting a day or so for better answers), accept it. This lets other understand both question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I hope to solve is how to deal with an Enum uniformly in Java. This Enum has a unified structure and a unified interface, but the Enumerator contained is different. See the above question for the specific situation. After @tgdavies' prompt, I moved the type parameter from the method definition to the interface definition, which solved the problem. Later, under the reminder of @Guillaume F., I further optimized the use of Enum. Thank you all for participating

Comment: Two questions extend here: First, is there any other way to traverse Enum's Enumator. Two, Java Generic can be used on type, but not on method